# Multiple query from multiple tables in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, sum

I am using it but no value i found...I think there is mistake in this query....Actually I want to know how to use multiple sum, multiplication etc using mutiple tables in sqlite

```
SELECT 
  dhid, dprice, dname,
  SUM(dmilk) AS totalmilk,
  dprice*SUM(dmilk) AS totalmilkamt,
  SUM(ghee) AS toalghee,
  SUM(ghee*gheeprice) AS totalgheeamt,
  SUM(ghee*gheeprice)+dprice*SUM(dmilk)  AS totals,
  SUM(cashamount)   AS totalcash,
  SUM(ghee*gheeprice)+dprice*SUM(dmilk)-SUM(cashamount) AS balance 
FROM
  (         SELECT *
              FROM costumer
   LEFT OUTER JOIN salesdata
                ON costumer.dhid=salesdata.ddhid
   LEFT OUTER JOIN cashdata
                ON salesdata.ddhid=cashdata.uid
               AND utype='costumer')
   WHERE dmonth='$mikdatem'
     AND dyear='$mikdatey' 
     AND dhid='$dhid' 
ORDER BY dhid ASC
```

Comment: Please format your query so that its structure becomes visible. Maybe then we can spot the error.

Comment: ok...i will try to edit....:)

Comment: Why are you trying to order by the `dhid` column, when your `WHERE` condition restricts it to exactly one value?

Comment: To find out what's going on, look at the result of only the inner `SELECT`, or only the inner `SELECT` with the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

Your select above will not help us because we don't have the underlying data to get an idea what you wish to do.

So the generalistic answer is this:
when using grouping-functions (SUM/COUNT...) you always require some form of "GROUP BY" to columns not used in those group-functions.

Example given:

```
SELECT name, sum(dmilk)
FROM milk_entry
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: @Najzero.....Thanks .....I know it...but how we can use sums of columns of various tables...and also other query like multiplication, division etc....using data from various tables.

Comment: @Najzero It *is* possible to use aggregate functions without `GROUP BY`; the result will be a single row.

Comment: I would need a minimalistic example if your data (2 rows in each table + how the result should be) to have a look. It seems your subquery could be removed and simply use it in one statement and then correctly applying a GROUP BY